# Who is Brenner in The Secret Generations?

Tags: character-analysis

I just finished The Secret Generations, a British spy novel set around 1910 by John Gardner, and one character I am wondering about is Brenner.

It is clearly mentioned that this is a codename for another character but which one?!

I am not sure if it is explicitly mentioned, or made clear in another way.